# Different Eclipse output for processor than machine

Tags: java

What does it mean when internally inside my desktop (purchased as used) I have **Core i7 processor** and in System info it says the same, but when I was programming in Eclipse editor for Java I typed `System.out.print (System.getProperty ("OS.arch"));` and it prints `amd64` in the console?

Does it mean I have different processor architecture and different processor inside? How can an AMD processor be replaced with Intel as their architectures are totally different?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?!? This is a very reasonable, useful and very specific question to ask!

Comment: This question was answered many times and answer is easy to find in google.

Comment: @yu.pitomets Please close suggest a duplicate if this question was asked and answered before on SO - I'll be happy to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> AMD's invention of a 64 bit "stretch" of the IA32 architecture which
>   they labeled "AMD64" came before Intel "invented" a compatible copy of
>   this architecture which they named "EM64T". There was no generic term
>   signify "both AMD64 and EM64T" in common use when 5.0 was created,
>   even though development at Intel was going on as "Yamhill" and the
>   rumor mill was buzzing vigorously for years.
>
> In the same way that the label "i386" is absolutely archiac but most
>   users understand it's meaning in a packaging or platform query
>   context, "amd64" will have to gain acceptance too, as use of this
>   label is not going to change.

Attribution: [OpenJDK bugs database: os.arch returns amd64 for Intel processor](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6378452)